# How to get values from another form C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i made a program that opens another form and in that form there are two buttons, when one of the buttons are clicked a varible is beening set and the form colses,
now i want to use thoes varible in my main form

Comment: Windows or web application?

Comment: While your buttons are likely to be private, why don't you just make those variables public? Then you can access them anywhere.

Comment: @LaneL, no, no, no! Never encourage public variables for sharing data, for that can only lead to tears (specifically around unreliable, untestable, code)

Comment: Do enlighten me on how to transfer data from one form to another without there being a public interface of some sort. Perhaps set them to internal assuming all forms are in the same assembly?